# Ubuntu 12.10 can't detect new hard drive

Tags: 12.10, drive, detect

So I was creating a partition table on my brand new Seagate 3TB HDD when a short power outage hit. Now, Ubuntu won't detect that the hard drive is their; it doesn't show up in gparted or `fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check a few things

1. check if its detected in the bios/uefi
2. check if there's an entry for it in /dev/

If its detected in both cases, the drive itself is fine and, you might be able to run shred on the device, then reformat it. Since its a 3tb drive, you might end up needing to use [gdisk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/gdisk.8.html) instead so you can format it as a GPT drive

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The hard drive is detected by my BIOS but there is no /dev/ entry.

Comment: thats curious, not even one for the root device?